# Proof that convergence almost everywhere is not topological.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have written the following proof that convergence almost everywhere is not topological, and I would like it checked if you guys please:

Assume that $\tau$ is the topology of almost everywhere convergence.

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions dominated by an integrable function.

Lemma: If $f_n\to f$ in $\tau$ then $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$.

Theorem: $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ implies $f_n\to f$ in $\tau$

Proof:

$f_n\to f$ in $L^1$  implies that every subsequence of $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$. But then for every subsequence of $f_n$, we have a subsequence (of the subsequence) that converges almost everywhere to $f$.

Thus, for every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$, there is a subsequence of that subsequence that converges to $f$ in $\tau$.

But $\tau$ is a topology and we can thus conclude that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $\tau$. End Of Proof.

Therefore, we have proved that convergence in $L^1$ for a set of measurable dominated functions implies almost everywhere convergence.

However, the typewriter sequence satisfies the hypothesis without converging almost everywhere.

Thus, we have proved a wrong theorem and thus our assumption that $\tau$ exists was wrong.

Thus, convergence almost everywhere is not topological.

Comment: You started by assuming that $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e., and you conclude that $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e.! Where's the contradiction?

Comment: No, I did not start by that. The first lemma and the second lemma are independent (I'm just saying what $f_n$ denotes). I proved the first lemma because I use it in the second.

Comment: The proof is actually the "Second" part.

Comment: "Every subsequence has a convergent subsubsequence with common limit implies the sequence itself converges to the same limit" works for metric spaces or topologies induced by gauges. In general it is not clear, at least not to me!

Comment: Topology of almost everywhere convergence may very likely fail to be first countable. So sequences are far to less to consider only! Nets instead may break the quivalence you're proving. Such an example actually exists: Banach weak and weak operator topology have the same convergent sequences but have different convergent nets thus they are distinct topologies!

Comment: But I'm proving that the almost everywhere convergence of sequences has no topology. The book defined almost everywhere convergence of sequences of functions, not of general nets.

Comment: And the first thing you asked about works by identifying sequences with nets and subsequences with cofinal subnets and the corresponding idea for nets.
I still don't get what first countability has to do with that regarding what I want to prove.

Comment: What is your ultimate argument that it does not admit a corresponding topology?

Comment: Topology is fully encoded in *sequences* only in *first countable* spaces!

Comment: The argument on convergence works in *metric* spaces and not in general *topological* spaces!

Comment: I dont get what you mean... Where did I imply the topology is encoded fully in sequences? The topology Im discussing is the one for sequences. Countability has nothing to do with it. Product topologies are the same as those of pointwise convergence, for example.

Comment: What shall this be?!?!! *("The topology [...] for sequences.")*